# weighted average of a list of dicts in python

Tags: python, dictionary, average, weighted-average

Given a list of dicts like the following:

```
[{'apple':2, 'banana':3, 'orange':4}, 
 {'apple':3, 'banana':15, 'orange':3},
 {'apple':4, 'banana':9, 'orange':1},
 {'apple':5, 'banana':11, 'orange':10}, ...]
```

What is an efficient way to calculate the exponential weighted mean for each key? E.g. the expected output will be a single dict like:

```
{'apple':x, 'banana':y, 'orange':z}
```

The simple average is relatively straightforward, but not sure how to modify it to do an exponential weighted average:

```
def dict_mean(dict_list):
    mean_dict = {}
    for key in dict_list[0].keys():
        mean_dict[key] = sum(d[key] for d in dict_list) / len(dict_list)
    return mean_dict
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "exponential weighted mean"?  Do you mean the exponentially weighted moving average?

Comment: yes, thats what i meant

Comment: A moving average creates several values for each category. If you aggregate into a single value, this is just an average (or weighted average)

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas is efficient and easy:

```
import pandas as pd

dicti = [{'apple':2, 'banana':3, 'orange':4}, 
 {'apple':3, 'banana':15, 'orange':3},
 {'apple':4, 'banana':9, 'orange':1},
 {'apple':5, 'banana':11, 'orange':10}]

# chose the dacay:
decay = 0.4

# notice that the ewm of an array returns another array not a number.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dicti).ewm(alpha=decay).mean()

# but you can take the last term with iloc:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dicti).ewm(alpha=decay).mean().iloc[-1]

# You can finally export it as a dictionary:
end_dict = df2.to_dict()
print(end_dict)
```

You can read more about exponential moving averages in pandas [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)